# unable to get the right object to set the windowState

Tags: vba, internet-explorer

I'm trying to put an IE window on the side of the screen as showed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60001809/change-excel-windows-sizes-to-half-the-screen/60002152?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C80.7685#60002152) but I'm unable to get the right object to set the windowState

**edit note: the code in the linked answer works with the Word Application only replacing "xlMaximized" with "wdWindowStateMaximize"**

this is my (not working) code:

```
Sub OpenNewIE()
Dim IE As Object, MyUrl As String
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
MyUrl = "https://www.google.com/"
IE.navigate MyUrl 
Stop
IE.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize' xlMaximized will not work
Stop
End Sub
```